# What does creating a file as "file.ext:file.ext" really do?

Tags: windows, cmd, steganography

I've recently started to look into steganography, and I've found a tutorial online where, to hide a new text file inside another file, the tutorial-giver used something similar to the following command:

```
    notepad.exe file.ext:textfile.txt
```

I find the `:` in the command line rather bizarre: Notepad recognized this as valid indexation for the file, and the original file (file.ext) now had an increased space on disk to contain the data from the new text file. As I know little and use cmd very scarcelly in my academic life, I would like to know what is going on here. What feature is this? What is it's intended use? Is this exclusive to the windows cmd or are there equivalences on UNIX?

Comment: That's a file stream. It's specific to NTFS (Windows, primarily). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-streams for details on what they are and how they work. That doesn't *hide a file inside another file*. It attaches an alternate file stream to the same file, but it's stored externally as an additional file on disk, not inside the original file.

Comment: Type `Dir /r` to list streams. `15/01/2016  08:07 AM         2,910,631 script56.chm` and on a second line `29 script56.chm:Zone.Identifier:$DATA`. This actual stream is used by Windows Explorer to say this file came from the Internet.

Comment: Once, but no more, comments could be stored about a file as a stream. But no one used it. Also Notepad is a test program for different Windows' features. Type `https://www.microsoft.com` (you have to get it right) in Notepad's File Open dialog. It's a feature for File Open dialogs that Notepad is a test for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

What you're looking at is an Alternate Data Streams (ADS) of a file in the NTFS file-system (FS).

#### Details:

In older operating systems (OS), one entry in a file-systems (FS) represented one set of data, which means that a file was just a file.  Newer OSes have modern FS which allow one entry to represent one or more sets of data.  In NTFS, these are called streams, and in other OSes these are commonly called forks. For this explanation, the two terms are synonymous.

In today's FS, every file will have at least 1 stream.  The first stream will have no name, and will have a type of `$DATA`.  The first stream is sometimes referred to as the primary, default, or anonymous stream.  All ADS beyond the first will have both a name and a type.  The default and most common stream type is `$DATA`.

The full name of a stream is of the form:

```
<filename>:<stream name>:<stream type>
```

#### Usage:

In Windows (focusing there since you mentioned `notepad.exe`), there are many uses for ADS.  The most common ADS people interact with (without even realizing it) is `Zone.Identifier`, which is added to files downloaded by Internet Explorer and some other browsers.  This extra, this additional data stream is used by the OS as a flag for 'potentially unsafe to run'.  Similarly, MS Office apps will use the same stream to caution users when opening docs which could contain malicious macros.  In all these cases, the user is warned, but not prevented from opening dangerous files.

#### Tools To Enum (examples, not exhaustive):

`dir /r` from `cmd.exe`

`Streams.exe` from SysInternals

`Get-Item` from `powershell.exe`

#### Demo: Create, Look, Read, Delete

```
c:\temp> dir /r ads_test*
File Not Found
```

```
c:\temp> echo this is normal text>ads_test.txt
c:\temp> dir /r ads_test*
04/11/2019  01:11 AM                21 ads_test.txt
```

```
c:\temp> echo this is text for an ADS>ads_test.txt:myHiddenAds
c:\temp> dir /r ads_test*
04/11/2019  01:12 AM                21 ads_test.txt
                                    25 ads_test.txt:myHiddenAds:$DATA
```

```
c:\temp> dir ads_test*
04/11/2019  01:12 AM                21 ads_test.txt
```

```
c:\temp> more < ads_test.txt
this is normal text
```

```
c:\temp> more < ads_test.txt:myHiddenAds
this is text for an ADS
```

```
c:\temp> type nul 2>ads_test.txt:myHiddenAds
c:\temp> dir /r ads_test*
04/11/2019  01:20 AM                21 ads_test.txt
                                     0 ads_test.txt:myHiddenAds:$DATA
```

```
c:\temp> echo this is yet another ADS>ads_test.txt:CashMeOutside
c:\temp> dir /r ads_test*
04/11/2019  01:24 AM                21 ads_test.txt
                                    25 ads_test.txt:CashMeOutside:$DATA
                                     0 ads_test.txt:myHiddenAds:$DATA
```

```
c:\temp> powershell.exe -c "& {get-item -path 'c:\temp\ads_test.txt' -stream * | ft -property FileName,Stream,Length}"
FileName             Stream        Length
--------             ------        ------
C:\temp\ads_test.txt :$DATA            21
C:\temp\ads_test.txt CashMeOutside     25
C:\temp\ads_test.txt myHiddenAds        0
```

```
c:\temp> powershell.exe -c "& {remove-item -path 'c:\temp\ads_test.txt' -stream myHiddenAds}"
c:\temp> powershell.exe -c "& {get-item -path 'c:\temp\ads_test.txt' -stream * | ft -property FileName,Stream,Length}"
FileName             Stream        Length
--------             ------        ------
C:\temp\ads_test.txt :$DATA            21
C:\temp\ads_test.txt CashMeOutside     25
```

#### Other Uses:

While it's not common, directories can have ADS as well.  In the case of directories, there is no default data stream, but there is a default directory stream. Directories are the stream type $INDEX_ALLOCATION. The default stream name for the type $INDEX_ALLOCATION (a directory stream) is $I30.  Although directories do not have a default data stream, they can have named data streams.

#### Issues:

In recent years, ADS have suffered some bad reputation since they have been used and abused by bad actors to write hidden data, store viruses, and maintain persistence.  Even today, many modern virus scanners are more capable of detecing threats from primary streams, when compared to ADS.  The Microsoft Defender, Advanced Threat Protection, and SmartScreen can detect ADS threats just as efficiently as from primary streams.

#### Demo2 - Non-Harmful Example Of How A Bad Actor Might Use ADS

```
C:\temp> echo asdf > \\?\c:\temp\COM1.txt
C:\temp> type c:\windows\system32\calc.exe> \\?\c:\temp\COM1.txt:TotallyNotMalware.exe
C:\temp> wmic process call create "\\?\c:\temp\COM1.txt:TotallyNotMalware.exe"
C:\temp> dir /r
04/11/2019  01:30 AM                21 ads_test.txt
                                    25 ads_test.txt:CashMeOutside:$DATA
04/11/2019  02:45 AM                 7 COM1.txt

C:\temp> rem Notice above that the ADS doesn't show - This is because "COM1" is a system reserved name, and many internal and 3rd party programs deal with it wrong.
```

#### Additional Readings:

[Miocrosoft - Windows protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/b134f29a-6278-4f3f-904f-5e58a713d2c5)

[Winitor - NTFS Alternate Data Streams](https://winitor.com/pdf/NtfsAlternateDataStreams.pdf)

[Enigma0x3 - Using alternate date streams to persist on a compormised machine](https://enigma0x3.net/2015/03/05/using-alternate-data-streams-to-persist-on-a-compromised-machine/)